# Mocking IDisposable classes

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, rhino-mocks, idisposable

Scenario: I've got a class that subscribes to a static event in its default constructor. As such, the class is made `IDisposable`, such that it can unsubscribe from the static event and be properly garbage collected. This class is being mocked in tests using `RhinoMocks`. It has composite part children, which may or may not be `IDisposable`.

Problem: I'm leaking these objects due to the Dispose method being automatically mocked by `RhinoMocks`. This causes 'random' errors in different tests due to the still subscribed objects reacting to events for which they are not properly set up.

Question: I know RhinoMocks has methods for stating that the original method should be called (`CallOriginalMethod`), but I've noticed that `RhinoMocks` sometimes creates proxies itself beyond my own declarations. As such, I don't think I can prevent those object from being leaked. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: That's not what `IDisposable` is for. You always have to call `Dispose` manually, so you can't rely on it ever being called. Static events are an awful pattern, and you should avoid them like the plague. I know this doesn't really answer your question, but you should revise your application design - if you rely on static events, you're likely doing something very wrong. At the very least, you should use your own event manager that will e.g. only use weak references (if that's your usage pattern) - if you find that the object has been collected in the meantime, just remove it from the manager.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with you @Luaan, that subscribing to static events can cause all kinds of problems and should be avoided. Sadly, this has been implemented in a clients' framework years ago, before I joined, and has become the integral part on managing application events... Refactoring is not an option I'm afraid, as no one will be paying for it. I've looked into weak event subscription, but haven't found anything that felt dependable or complete. You know a good source, I'm all ears :)

Answer (score 0):

When you mock a class you can pass in additional interfaces (or types) to implement (e.g. IDisposable)

During the tear down phase of the unit test you can cast the mocked object to a type of IDisposable and call Dispose

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not follow? Could you please elaborate on that? Perhaps with a (pseudo-code) example?